# Is it possible to list fields actually used from result sets in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, dataset

I have dozens of SSRS Reports and the corresponding stored procedures that I am slowly cleaning up and optimizing, I am finding a number of data sets that have extra fields that are not used in the actual report, they are usually the result of a `SELECT *` that is slowing down the SP end of things significantly in a few places.

I am wondering if there is a quicker way to see which fields from the datasets are used/unused to more efficiently clean up the stored procedures. It seems like clicking through to each `<<expr>>` and checking them off is a ridiculous way to go about this.

Comment: What you want is selecting the required number of columns at the database level itself so that your dataset has only what it needs. I am sorry, in this case, you will have to get down into the Stored Procedures and take care of them.

Comment: I know that :), that's pretty much the background of my question.  But these are stored procedures and reports that have existed for years, most of them have subscriptions delivered daily, so I would like to avoid breaking them while I work if at all possible.

Comment: How is this not a feature in VS yet?

Answer (score 2):

I'll tell you, I wish I knew a tool that simplifies this for you.
And I don't off the top of my head.
But for sure I know you can search the text of the rdl and find these details.

I do this often when troubleshooting problems with existing reports (or SSIS packages).

The .rdl files are human-readable xml.
You can open any one file in a text editor and search the text - even Visual Studio if you "Open File" rather than use the Report project.

Given that, of course you can write a routine in your preferred programming language that

- finds the query or proc in the data source of the Report
- runs it (as metadata only) to get all the columns
- search for each one in the text of the rdl
- you can be more specific if you use xml queries to limit
  the search to more realistic targets like display box Data Sources

Sorry I don't have a more convenient answer like an existing tool.

If I remember, I may look for one because this is a big problem for "corporate coders" like us.

If I can't find one, maybe I'll write the script in .net and come back and post it :)

Comment: I wrote a quick .NET solution that does this.  First it attaches to the report server and pulls the RDL as XML.  Then it converts it to XDocument format so I can use LINQ for XML.  Next it makes a list of data fields from the <Fields> section.  Finally it searches the <ReportSections> for each field.  The final output is a list of fields and whether they are in use or not.  If there is any interest I can post some sample code?

Comment: I'm really interested Richard. I know this post is old but if you still have the sample code, you'd make me very happy!

Gr. Mike

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can ! Use the following steps

- right click the rdl file and
- click the View Code . This will be an XML format
- CTR + F to get a search text box
- Enter the name of any field in the text box.
- Use the Forward Arrow icon to see the number of occurrence of the searched field name
- If the text field is in the dataset and Tablixcell value, then it shows it's being used in the report
- If the text field is only in the dataset and not any tablixcell value, then it's not being used in the report.